# umlaut not working on some browsers

Tags: html, browser, character-encoding, compatibility

Hi Guys This is a rather frustrating problem...

I have a german client and the site is mostly in german now on some machines in the office all the special characters (umlauts n such) display correctly in chrome firefox and ie but on the clients pc and my own the characters are displayed like this

```
Interessierte Paare, die an diesem spektakulÃ¤ren Ort in der sÃ¼dlichsten Hochzeitskapelle     Afrikas heiraten mÃ¶chten, wenden sich bitte an
```

here is my code in

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Now from what i have found online while researching this matter is that utf-8 is supposed to handle all characters? obviously i am missing something here?

i find it rather strange that it doesnt work on the same version of browser on two different machines?

if you would like to see the site and see for yourself its [capeagulhas-arthouse.com](http://capeagulhas-arthouse.com) - not sure if i can have links here but there it is

Please any help is much appreciated

EDIT: forgot to mention this is a joomla site

Tx 
Ant

Comment: The actual http headers, including the response header, etc look good, so I would be checking your source html files, maybe they have been saved as some other format.

Comment: Thank you, i will be looking into this,please clarify what you mean by "some other format"?

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are using joomla, joomla uses iso-8859-1 encoding by default.

Go to your language file and look for

```
DEFINE('_ISO','charset=iso-8859-1');
```

Change it to

```
DEFINE('_ISO','charset=utf-8');
```

Comment: Ok that sounds promising thank you very much for the input perhaps you could tell me where i might find the language file? i have a language folder on server with index.html and subfolders overrides, en-GB and de-DE

Comment: Ok nothing seems to be working so far - i cannot find *define* in the language file (apparently this version of joomla (1.5) doesnt use the define method? - and the problem seems to be only since the website has transferred hosting companies? from a German company to a South African company i have contacted both providers and still no solution but it absolutely has to be something that was supported in germany but isn't supported here with the SA host? what would be the easiest way to find out? so many variables my brain is sore lol :)

Answer (score 0):

An incorrect code conversion has been applied. From the given data, I cannot deduce where it has happened and how it can be prevented. But what clearly has happened is that UTF-8 encoded text has been incorrectly transformed so that each byte of in UTF-8 data is treated as if it were a windows-1252 encoded form of a character, and the result is then presented as UTF-8.

It is such an incorred “double UTF-8” encoding that turns e.g. “ä” to “Ã¤”. The letter “ä” (U+00E4) is the two byes C3 A4 (hex.) in UTF-8. Now if you mistakenly interpret these as windows-1252, you get U+00C3 U+00A­4, i.e. “Ã¤”.